# javascript page navigation not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I am new with javascript.

I wanted to navigate the page on sucessfull, enterance of loginID and password.

(for the time being, i have programmed for any login id and password, validation kind of work).

For that i have used `location.replace("Registration.aspx");`

**My code is following:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var flag = 0; 
        function Validate() {
            if (document.getElementById('txtLoginId').value == "") {

                flag = 1;

                document.getElementById('lblLoginID').innerHTML = "Enter LoginID";

            }
            else {

                document.getElementById('lblLoginID').innerHTML = " ";

            }

            if (document.getElementById('txtPassWord').value == "") {
                flag = 1;
                alert("dddddd"+flag);
                document.getElementById('lblPassword').innerHTML = "Enter Password";

            }
            else {

                document.getElementById('lblPassword').innerHTML = "";

            }

            if (flag == 1) {

                return false;

            }
            else {

               // Response.Redirect("Registration.aspx");
                  location.replace("Registration.aspx");
                return true;

            }

        }

    </script>
```

**Button Code:**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="LogIn" 
                            onclick="btnLogin_Click" OnClientClick="return Validate();" />
```

What can be mistake in it?

Please help me.

Comment: @MitchWheat sorry if any spelling mistake or sentence construction, english is not my primary language

Comment: You are mixing client and server side. Use location.replace(URL) instead of asp redirect. Or in this case simply remove the redirect and make the button a submit button or even better, bind the submit of the form instead of the button

Comment: wait i will see to it

Comment: I wasn't having a go at your language. It was an attempt at humor. Obviously a poor attempt.

Comment: I used window.location.href also, but not worked

Comment: I wonder why you don't just use the asp.net **RequiredFieldValidator** control?

Comment: my TL says it increases load over application, so use java script validations

Comment: RequiredFieldValidator also uses javascript validation. The difference is it renders the script for you :) Anyway, what happen when the button is clicked. Is there any server side code to execute in `btnLogin_Click`?

Comment: yeah, i wanted to reder it client side, but failed, so now i rendered it with server side, Response.Redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have to process the input from user in code behind:

Client script validation function should be like this:

```
    function Validate() {
        var flag = 0;

        if (document.getElementById('txtLoginId').value == "") {
            flag = 1;
            document.getElementById('lblLoginID').innerHTML = "Enter LoginID";
        }
        else 
            document.getElementById('lblLoginID').innerHTML = " ";

        if (document.getElementById('txtPassWord').value == "") {
            flag = 1;
            document.getElementById('lblPassword').innerHTML = "Enter Password";
        }
        else 
            document.getElementById('lblPassword').innerHTML = "";

        return (flag != 1);

    }
```

In code behind:

```
public void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /* username and password processing code
    ....
    */
    Response.Redirect("Registration.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a serverside function

```
Response.Redirect
```

on client side code. Use

```
window.location
```

on client.

Answer (score 1):

```
 location.replace("Registration.aspx");
                return false;
```

`return false` instead of `return true`.It will work.